# How to get a smooth circle using Loop tool function

Tags: modeling

I already have made a circle shape mesh, but its not a perfect circle, how can I make the outer mesh a perfect circle? I try the loop tools, but it distorts the topology.

[image]

Comment: weird. can u provide blend file? i tried it and it worked for me

Comment: maybe try the To Sphere operation (shortcut Alt Shift S)

Comment: Here's the file: https://easyupload.io/zu7ohl

I tried the sphere operation, and its doing the same thing distorting the shape.